# How to save jpeg image after replacing LSB in DCT with the Jsteg method?

Tags: java, jpeg, steganography

I am using the Jsteg method, but i have a confusion, something i don't quite understand.The steps are:

1. Get 8x8 pixel block
2. Discret cosine tranform
3. Quantization
4. Replace the Least Significant Bit

What i don't understand is, when i open the image in java using BufferedImage and ImageIO and do these steps, how do i save the changes? if i write:

```
ImageIO.write(img,"jpg",new_img);
```

does java recompress the image and then the hidden text is lost, or when it does the compression it doesn't change anything since i did compress manually?
or should i save it in another way?
Bottom line:After replacing LSB, how to save the encoded image ?

Comment: You're going to have to use a JPEG library and modify it it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Steganography in lossy compression (JAVA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29677726/steganography-in-lossy-compression-java)

Comment: Well that doesn't solve the problem i have, all i need to know if after replacing the LSB, how should i save the image ?

Comment: Read more carefully. The answer on how to save the image is exactly what user3344003 (and I) suggested. You need to use a jpeg library and modify the steps to include your steganographic algorithm in the process. Embedding your secret and then just calling `ImageIO.write()` or any other such function starts the compression process all over again.

Comment: Oh! my bad, thank you, this really helped me .